# Trouble with a simple jQuery array

Tags: jquery, arrays

Maybe I'm tired, but I'm having trouble with something.

I need structure an array so it looks like:

```
{period:'2010-01',revenues:2000},{period:'2010-02',revenues:2200},....
```

I have this so far:

```
var data = {period:key,revenues:amount};
```

Which is in a jQuery.each function and works fine, but I cannot figure out how to put each iteration of data into an array that is structured like above.

I've tried:

dataArray += data;

dataArray.push(data); (this doesn't work because I can't have the keys)

Answer (score 1):

You have an object `{}`. This is an array: `[]`. What you can do is push the objects into an array:

```js
    var myArr = [];
    var myData = {'key':'value'};
    myArr.push(myData);
    console.log(myArr);
```